# Spotify API -User's Albums hidden tracks

Tags: spotify, hidden

I am quite new to the Spotify WebAPI. 
No problems to get the users's saved albums, but reading data of the albums always results in **ALL** available tracks of each album.

In the Spotify app I've deselected some tracks though (in the app these tracks are not displayed when having clicked on the - icon).
How can I get the same result using the API? Must be stored anywhere.

Thanks Uli